# how to change separate layouts for portrait and landscape in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

how to change separate layouts for portrait and landscape in fragments?  I am working on a project which has one activity and 6 fragments .for the 6 fragments i am using separate layouts for both portrait and landscape but when the orientation changes the activity is getting restarted but while using @override on config changes method the activity remains still but the layout which i have created for landscape is not occurring the portrait layout itself changing what should i do ?

Comment: Did you create separate xml layout file for `values` and `values-land`

Comment: @nhoxbypass s created .